# limit of $ f(n) = 100 \left (1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) ^{ n}$

Tags: probability, limits, functions

So I was daydreaming about math (like I do frequently) and I came up with this question/riddle.

Say you have a die. If you roll a 1 you lose, otherwise, you win. This die has *n* sides on it, and you roll the die *n* times. Are your odds better with a large n, or a small n?

If figured out that the function to calculate your odds of winning (with n sides and n rolls) is 
$$ f(n) = 100 \left (1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) ^{ n}$$

Using this function, I found out the larger the n, the better your odds of not rolling a 1. I made a short python program [here](http://repl.it/UIq) to try and see what it converges upon. It seems to converge upon 36.7877 ish, but how do I find out what the exact limit is?

I think that this might be an important number, and it reminds me of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29#Compound_interest) question. I'm not claiming that this would be as important as e, but it seems like it should be important.

TL;DR What is the limit of 
$\displaystyle f(n) = 100 \left (1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) ^{ n}$, as n approaches infinity?

Comment: Are you familiar with $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+x^{-1})^x=e$? Some arithmetic with that yields that your limit is $\frac{100}{e}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a well-known result that:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{a}{n}\right)^n = e^{a}
$$

In this case, $a = -1$ and $e^{-1} \approx 0.367879441\ldots$

**Derivation.**

Take the log of the equation, we get:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{a}{n}\right)^n = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}n\log(1+\frac{a}{n})}
$$
Restate the exponent as:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log(1+\frac{a}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}
$$

Now we have an indeterminate form of $\frac{0}{0}$ and can apply L'hopital:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1 + \frac{a}{n}}\cdot a \frac{-1}{n^2}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}
$$
The powers of $n$ go to infinity at exactly the same rate, so they cancel, leaving:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{a}{n}}\cdot a
$$
Which is just $a$, so the original limit is $e^a$.

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty close with that program, but slightly off. I knew it was related to e!

Answer (score 3):

The $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e^{-1}$ so the overall $\lim_{n\to\infty}100(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n}=100e^{-1}\approx 36.7879$.

Comment: I think that it would be better to post the proof of your claim starting from the limit definition of $e$ to make a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to+\infty}100\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n&=
\lim_{n\to+\infty}100\left(1+\frac{1}{-n}\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to+\infty}100\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{-n}\right)^{-n}\right]^{-1}\\
&=100e^{-1}\\
&=\frac{100}{e}.
\end{align*}
$$